# linear program, why is there an outgoing arc such that $ d(s,v) = w(s,v)$

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

If any other information is needed, please feel free to ask me. I'm beginning my learning in graph theory and in optimization.

Let's call $D = (V,A)$ a directed graph. $w : A \to \mathbb R$, arc weights, $s \in V$. We also assume that there is a path from $s$ to any other vertex of $V$.
The linear program is the following :

$$ \max \sum_{v \in V \backslash  { s } } x_v  $$ 
s.t. $$ x_v - x_u \leq w(u,v) , \forall (u,v) \in A$$
$$ x_s \leq 0.$$

apparently, if there is no negative cycle in $D$, there has to be an outgoing arc $(s,v) \in A $ such that $d(s,v) = w(s,v)$. **Do you know why ?**

$d(u, v) $ denotes the length of the shortest path from $u$ to $v. $

Comment: So $w(s,v)$ is the weight of the edge $s \to v$ in $D$, but what is $d(s,v)$ in this context?

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the fact that by definition
$$
d(s,v) = \min_{u|(u,v) \in A}\{d(s,u) + \omega(u,v) \}
$$
Indeed, this is equivalent to 
$$
d(s,v) \le d(s,u) + \omega(u,v) \quad \forall (u,v) \in A
$$
or 
$$
d(s,v) - d(s,u) \le  \omega(u,v) \quad \forall (u,v) \in A
$$

Comment: What represents u in my question? I m sorry i m really lost. And you can do that bc there is no negative cycle, then distance is well defined?

Comment: $u$ is a predecessor of $v$

Comment: Yes this is only true is there are no cycles.

Comment: Oh so since u = s in my case, d(u, s) =0. But you give an inequality and i need an equality.